# Trying to make a search-function (for-each) print out an error message when no matches is found

Tags: java, for-loop, cannot-find-symbol

Im very new to Java and keep making trivial mistakes all the time. Im sure this is just another, but Im having a really hard time grasping the concept of this one. This is what my code looks like right now.

```
public void lstMatching(String searchString)
{
    for(String filename : files) {
        if(filename.contains(searchString)) {
            System.out.println(filename);
        }
        else{
            boolean invalid = true;
        }
    }
    if(invalid){
            System.out.println("Your search did not match any results.");
    }
}
```

What im trying to do is get the method to print out my error message when the searchString matches no single filename. Why do i keep getting an error-message saying my "invalid"-variable is wrong?

Comment: You need to declare the `boolean invalid` outside of the for loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note the following:

- `invalid` is known only in the `else` scope, so when you try to use it in the `if` statement - which is outside the `else` scope, it's not known. See the [The Java™ Tutorials - Variables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html) for detailed explanation
- You can simplify your code:

  ```
  public void lstMatching(String searchString)
  {
      boolean valid = false;
      for (String filename : files) {
          if (!filename.contains(searchString)) {
              // if logic here
          } else {
              // print
          }
      }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare your `invalid` variable before the loop. Also, you seem to have inverted your logic. You only need one match to be satisfied, so you should update the variable when you find a match:

```
public void lstMatching(String searchString)
{
    boolean invalid = true;
    for(String filename : files) {
        if(filename.contains(searchString)) {
            System.out.println(filename);
            invalid = false;
        }
    }
    if (invalid){
            System.out.println("Your search did not match any results.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Otherwise invalid variable will be only available in your `else` scope

Answer (score 1):

The "invalid" variable is declared in else part. 
If the file is found, then "invalid" variable is not declared since it doesn't go in else part). And you are trying to use that variable to check if file was found.

```
public void lstMatching(String searchString)
{
    boolean invalid = false;

    for(String filename : files) {
        if(filename.contains(searchString)) {
            System.out.println(filename);
        }
        else{
            invalid = true;
        }
    }
    if(invalid){
            System.out.println("Your search did not match any results.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use JDK8 just do that stuff with few line of code only :

```
public void lstMatching(String searchString) {
        if (Arrays.asList(files).stream().anyMatch(s -> s.contains(searchString))) {
            System.out.println("Your search matched");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Your search did not match any results.");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First problem you are facing because of the else block, because for loop will check all the files and if your file is in between the file names, it will still return true(Because the inValid variable value will always be dependable on the name of last file, if last name not matches then inValid will be true otherwise false).

Declare the inValid variable before the for loop and initialize it with the value true and in for loop if it finds the name of the file then simply change in inValid variable to true and break because you don't need to check further.

```
public void lstMatching(String searchString)
{
    boolean invalid = true;
    for(String filename : files) {
        if(filename.contains(searchString)) {
            System.out.println(filename);
            invalid = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (invalid){
            System.out.println("Your search did not match any results.");
    }
}
```

let me know if you find any difficulty by commenting below.